# text view on camera preview

Tags: android, textview, android-camera

I am developing a camera app. I want to display a text view on the camera preview. If I add the text view, the app will show the text view with the default text. When I do setText, the app is crashing. Can any body tell what might be the reason for this?

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

java code:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
text.setText("hi");
```

If I comment out setText line then app will display the default text.

Comment: what is the error in log cat?

Answer (score 1):

Your log suggests that textView1 is not available at that stage of onCreate(). When do you load the layout? Can you setText() later?

Answer (score 1):

Have you called `setContentView()` before calling `findViewById()`?